# OWA draft folder doesn't sync up wint Outlook 2007 (when using Citrix)

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-web-app

I have a user logging in to Citrix Server (on Windows 2003) to use Outlook 2007. In OWA, he sees all his drafts in Draft Folder and can easily access them, but when he is Citrix, he can see the folder, but not the messages.

I had him check **Normal** and **Favorite Folders** under **View** -> **Navigation Pane** as well as execute **outlook /cleanviews** to no help.

I should also clarify, we host exchange locally and it syncs up with Outlook 2007 in Citrix. Remote users use either OWA for access or login to Citrix and use Outlook 2007. In his case ***ALL*** folders appear in Outlook 2007, but draft folder doesn't show any saved messages, even though in OWA messages are there and he can edit, delete and send them.

Please, help!

Thanks!!!

Comment: what version of exchange are you running? can you see the item in the drafts folder using ExFolders or pfdavadmin?

Comment: @longneck Thanks, sometimes I let it go too long to accept an answer to see if there could be more.

Comment: @longneck I don't believe ExFolders will work, because it's Outlook 2007 sitting on Citrix and the pfdavadmin command comes back as an unknown command.  It is Exchange 2010 SP1.

Comment: Exfolders doesn't care what the client is or where it's run from. You need to download exfolders to and run it on an exchange server. That is the next step in this diagnostic process.

Comment: @longneck On it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cached mode in Outlook 2007? In cached mode, the Drafts and Outbox folders are local only.

Comment: No to cached mode (one of the 1st things I checked), plus I don't think you can do it in Citrix.  Yes and no, OWA directly syncs to the Exchange server, so draft, technically wouldn't be a local folder in that case.